# NopCommerce : Error while running the 'Keep alive' schedule task

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, nopcommerce

I have been getting this error on Nopcommerce all day, the site was workign normally before then all of a sudden started getting

> Error while running the 'Keep alive' schedule task. The remote server
>   returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.System.Net.WebException:
>
> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
>   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest&
>   request)    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)    at
>   Nop.Services.Common.KeepAliveTask.Execute() in
>   C:\Users\spadmin\Documents\WebStorm\CVLWeb\Libraries\Nop.Services\Common\KeepAliveTask.cs:line
>   27    at Nop.Services.Tasks.Task.Execute(Boolean throwException,
>   Boolean dispose, Boolean ensureRunOnOneWebFarmInstance) in
>   C:\Users\spadmin\Documents\WebStorm\CVLWeb\Libraries\Nop.Services\Tasks\Task.cs:line
>   163

I have tried all the suggestion from the forum which include updating the KeepAlive link in Common/KeepAlive.cs, to create a file ina folder called KeepAlive in the Root.

The WebSite was running fine until this morning when the error started showing up. I am running version 3.9 of NopCommerce on Azure Website.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the keep will just ping the Store URL. Could you please confirm the store URL and add a / at the end? You can also try to change the URL. Has the URL changed?

Comment: The store URL has not changed, this was working before and all of a sudden just stopped working and started giving this error, where do I update this, is it in the common/keepalive.cs??

Answer (score 0):

first check this 
1.Go to admin area > configuration > stores > your store details and ensure that store URL is entered with HTTP://